# How can I save CPU effort in SceneKit rendering delegates?

Tags: macos, scenekit, energy

SceneKit calls its rendering delegates sixty times a second to allow a host application to adjust parameters in the contained scene to provide animation, physics, etc.

My scene is large (360,000 vertices). Almost all (~95%) of the scene is rotated slightly every minute (every 3,600 delegate calls). A very small remainder of the scene (about 300 nodes ~ 15,000 vertices) is moved once a second (every 60 delegate calls); all the nodes are created and their properties set before the application 'starts' (in `viewDidLoad`) and then only their positions are changed, as described above, in the delegate calls.

My frame refresh rate only just keeps at 60 fps and CPU usage is about 30% according to Xcode. All that effort is being expended in the rendering loop (there's no interaction; no other work) so I have two questions:

1) does 30% CPU seems reasonable, given this general description of my app? More specifically, since my delegate code seems simple and invoked from <2% of the rendering loops, could I really be driving SceneKit to its limits?

2) if so, are there any SceneKit tricks to clawing back some CPU? Can the delegate call rate be slowed, for example?

*This is with macOS 10.12.3 and Xcode 8 (Swift 3) on a 2.8GHz/i7 2015 MacBook Pro*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Creating `SCNLevelOfDetail` objects for your geometries is worth a try.

Is anything else moving? Can you reduce your view's `preferredFramesPerSecond`?

Comment: I'll look at `SCNLevelOfDetail` .. new to me.  The `preferredFramesPerSecond` variable is only available to >macOS 10.12 (but it has good effect there).  A new discovery is the render loop spends almost all it's time in "Metal Flush" ..

Comment: I don't move the camera distance from the scene (yet), so `SCNLevelOfDetail` doesn't help for now.

Comment: Did you try it? You're almost certainly putting more vertices into the scene than you have pixels, so reducing that count (with LOD) will reduce the amount of stuff you're rendering.

Comment: Not yet, Hal, it'll take a little while to construct a lower resolution model.  I must admit I've made no effort to reduce the work I'm giving the GPU to do because I've heard how powerful they are.  I'm letting the GPU do all the work of hidden vertex/line removal, for example.  And I guess a core part of my issue here is, "am I expect too much?"

Comment: "Is anything else moving?" .. no, ~95% is static.  A little experimenting with `preferredFramesPerSecond` shows less CPU usage (good) but that frame rate is universal and impacts all rendering, so, for example, moving the camera [via `swipeAction` in the SCNView] results also in jerky motion due to the lower fps setting.  FWTW, at 60fps, camera motion, swiping, is buttery smooth with no detectable impact on CPU usage.  If the following statement makes sense, it feels like Apple's motion generation 'behind the scene' is advantaged over my motion generation via the delegate calls.

Comment: The LOD essentially constructs a lower resolution model for you. For example, you don't need all 360k vertices if you're rendering the object in a 1 inch square in your frame. That said though, if you're seeing buttery smooth scrolling at 60 fps, and don't need to worry about battery life, I'd say you should declare victory and be happy.

Comment: I constructed a new lower resolution model with 85,000 vertices (instead of 350,000), and the behavior is much improved.  CPU% is about the same as before at 25% (of 800%) but the "Metal Flush" time is down to about 6.5mS, less that half the render loop duration (previously it was 100%, or more, of the render loop time).  I'm still trying to parse the documentation related to `SCNLevelOfDetail` but, for now, I've gained some headroom.

Comment: I'll also note that I started this question worrying about how I could improve my code in the delegate callbacks.  In fact, my time in the delegate call was only ~0.1mS of the 17mS render loop and the high observed CPU usage was all 'behind the scenes' in Apple's code.  I'm not being critical of SceneKit .. but that's why improving the *model* (not the code) was the right way to improve performance.  There is probably more that I could do go to make SceneKit's life even easier .. I live and learn!

Answer (score 2):

How about trying to flatten the nodes and it's children using [`flattenedClone`](https://developer.apple.com/reference/scenekit/scnnode/1407960-flattenedclone?language=objc).

Comment: I actually don't have many nodes (about 400) and one node is a very detailed line geometry with about 350,000 vertices [so it's already like I 'flattened' it].  Would it be more efficient to break that up into, for example, 100 nodes of 3,500 vertices [given the description of `flattenedClone` suggests fewer nodes is better, I'd guess not].  I feel like I'm reverse engineering SceneKit here!